# When is it too late to get BCH and BTG from the fork from an appropriate wallet?

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-cash

Is it enough that the funds where sent before the forks on the blockchain, or should they also have been recieved (enough with 1 confirmation on the blockchain?)  before the forks, and why?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it enough that the funds where sent before the forks on the blockchain, or should they also have been recieved (enough with 1 confirmation on the blockchain?) before the forks

The bitcoins must have been recieved BEFORE the hardfork.

> and why?

If I understood it correctly, an unconfirmed transaction during the hardfork means "that the BTC's are still on the sender's adress".
Why? Because the people behind BCH/BTG copy the whole blockchain at one moment and if your transaction is unconfirmed => it's not in the blockchain => they can't copy it.
And that means that the sender of the BTC will have access to the BCH/BTG and the receiver gets nothing of that.